# get array field from postgreql database with libpqxx

Tags: c++, arrays, postgresql, libpqxx

In my PostgreSQL database I have a table with boolean[32] array field (let it be called "mask"). How can I fill C++ bolean array with data from "SELECT mask FROM mytable WHERE " query? For integer fields I get them like this: int myInteger = row["my_integer"].as(), but for arrays it can't be used.